# Django Admin page - adding new positions to module

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

I'm planning to create my first project in Django - shops database, but I have some concerns, as I read some tutorials.

I like the admin page concept, but have a question:

When adding a shop I want user to be able to add some product positions related to it, like - item -> price, but their number won't be the same every time. How to solve this in the admin panel? and what would be the best solution in the database for it? One table for shops, and other one with products, each related to a certain shop?
(Example: the list would look like this: user has a shop adding form, and there is a "+" for adding products. When he clicks it, a new pair of inputs product -> price appears and so on..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django you define the database structure via your Models. So, as you say, you would have one model for Shop and another for Product, and Product would have a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field to Shop.

What you want is possible in the Django admin. Have a look at [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) in the docs. You would have an admin page for Shop, with inline admin for Products.

I would strongly recommend you install [Grapelli](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-grappelli/) which is "a jazzy skin for the Django admin interface" and makes inline admins work nicer by providing javascript that allows you to add extra Product rows by clicking a + button, as you want.

Comment: The + button is there in Django 1.4 as well